# JAVA: Using RSA and SHA-1 need to transmit data from client to server (Digital Signature)

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, sha1

My requirement is to write a JAVA program which provides confidentiality and integrity of data transmission from a client to the server.

For which am planning to use RSA and SHA-1 hash methods. Also need to set up a network connection between a client and a server and exchange the message. Server should verify the signature and check for the integrity.

So I just wanted to know, is there any documents which would help me in writing it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a homework.

Comment: Your requirement is met entirely by TLS. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: @Daenarys yeah sort of homework, but am new to network programming so googling and trying get help from here as well :)

Comment: @EJP am not sure about TLS. will check the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to try it yourself using code I guess. - http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.security.KeyPair

In using Java, you can use javax.security Keypair using RSA and SHA-1, sign with the parameters you wanted to include. Send private key to server, then each time you request something, verify at the server with public key of generated keypair with correct parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much :) will work on it